# How do I set the language for the Android developer website?

Tags: android, documentation

When I attempt to navigate to the Android developer website, I am redirected to a version of it much of which is in Chinese. For instance, if I try to navigate to:

```
developer.android.com
```

I am redirected to:

```
http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/index.html
```

I want the English language site. In some cases, I've had to have web pages translated from Chinese. What am I doing wrong? How can I suppress this behavior?

Comment: The default language of my operating system and Google account is English. I don't understand why it keep changing the documentation language to Brazilian Portuguese or Russian.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

While CommonsWare's answer will work just fine because removing the cookie will reset the language back to the default (English), the proper way to change the language of the Android Developer site to English is use the language spinner at the bottom of the page. This will set your preference and should retain it (by saving off the preference to the cookie).

[image]

Comment: This has been bugging me forever. The dropdown at the very bottom fixed it once and for all. I prefer this route over deleting the cookies.

Comment: I just right click the web page and it shows option for translate to english it works for me

Answer (score 7):

You can also just append ***“&hl=en”*** to the end of the URL and reload the page.

That will trigger a prompt asking you if you want to set the default language to English (or whatever you want).

Answer (score 6):

For others who may have this problem, the Google search will often try to redirect you to your specific locale page.

I didn't notice that at first, since the process is very instinctive (*type and click*) and thought the site was constantly changing my language back to Portuguese. I solved it by changing my Google Search [language setting](https://www.google.com.br/preferences?hl=pt#languages) to English once for all.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

Since I got the same effect in my browser after visiting that `zh-cn` URL once, you presumably clicked on a link to the Chinese edition somewhere along the line.

> How can I suppress this behavior?

Well, you can switch back to English by removing the cookies from the `developer.android.com` domain, at least in my quick test.

I am not aware of a way to prevent you from ever visiting the Chinese site.

Comment: This solution is permanent for this problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I set up the spinner at the bottom to English, but still got the content in another language.
I changed chrome language setting, then finally it changed to English.

1. Go to setting on the upper right of chrome.
2. Find language -> click language setting.
3. Drag English to the top of the language list.