# How do I change the language of Android Studio manual

Tags: android, android-studio

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html

Somehow I have left side in English and content side in Portuguese. It`s annoying and there is no options or something so I could change this. Please help.

Comment: Look at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question

Comment: @Zoe and other close voters: [questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Makyen website documentation isn't considered one of them, specifically when it comes down to "how do I change the language"

Comment: @Zoe So, you're arguing that it's not a tool which is commonly used by programmers?

Comment: @Makyen no, I'm arguing this question is basically customer service. Equivalently, app stores are software tools commonly used by programmers, but questions about them are still off-topic

Comment: @Zoe There's a line between what's customer service and what's using the tools. In general, it falls on the customer service side if it requires us to know something about policies, the customers account, etc. It's not customer service if it's just using the tool.

Comment: @JonClements Did you wanna restore [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32029945), then? I would've hammered this as a duplicate of that, but it went bye-bye, so I just figured we should be consistent.

Comment: @MikeM. seems reasonable - it's borderline on-topic depending how one interprets things, but seems it comes up now and again and is useful for others, so might as well have a reference to it instead of repeated questions. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer that helped me. Now it is now removed.

I know that question might be out of programming area. Also it was very annoying when it changed language for me somehow. Felt like of using Windows, the worst OS ever made. There is no clues to see on the bottom, when Google usually asks to look for the top. So, thank you very much to downvote this pretty heavily. You are so humans out there.

The answer is. Look at the bottom, there is drop-down menu with languages. Who would of thought.